# How to get currentUser on first load in firebase-auth without requesting

Tags: firebase, authentication, vue.js, firebase-authentication

I'm using firebase authentication, and my navbar is depend on if user is logged in or not. When i load the website, if user not logged out before, he should still stay as logged in.But, Firebase onAuthStateChanged listener returns user after 100-300ms, so my navbar can't decide if user is logged in or not.So, navbar shows login and signup button for 300ms, then firebase returns user, and navbar shows dashboard and logout button.

I'm using vue, I've tried saving UID and username on localstorage, but i'm concerning about security. what if someone manually changed localstorage data? Also, user may logged out, but stay logged in my manually setting localStorage.setItem('user', ....)

Navbar.vue

```
<div v-if="user.uid" class="flex row space-b">
   // userpic, photo, logout button
</div>
<div v-else>
   // login and signup button 
</div>
```

vuex

```
state: {
user: {
  uid: null,
  photoURL: null,
  username: null,
},
},
```

I tried not to mount Vue instance until onAuthStateChanged listener returns something, but this can't be a good solution, hence i'm rendering website nearly 300ms late.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/62321683/4050261

Answer (score 1):

The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73493256/4050261) given by @Abdullah Alhariri works. But, it stops VUE to load unless the firebase auth has initialised. This can result into long period of blank screen for users.
Here is a solution (inspired from [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xceR7mrrXsA) by LearnVue.

The main.js file should not contain any import or reference to the firebase.

Add `firebase.js` in the `src/helper` folder.
In this file, we are setting up firebase project and auth. The important part is `getCurrentUser()` function. This will be used in router.js

```js
// Firebase App (the core Firebase SDK) is always required and must be listed first
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
// Add the Firebase products that you want to use
import { getAuth, onAuthStateChanged } from 'firebase/auth';

// Firebase config we got from firebase console.
const firebaseConfig = {
  // Your config
};

// Initlise Firebase
const firebaseApp = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
// Authentication
export const fbAuth = getAuth(firebaseApp);


export async function getCurrentUser() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // If the user is already found, then the firebase is initialized.
    //  In this case, simply return the user.
    if (fbAuth.currentUser) {
      resolve(fbAuth.currentUser)
      return
    }
    // The user is not found, hence listen to the change
    const removeListener = onAuthStateChanged(
      fbAuth,
      (user) => {
        removeListener(); // After initialized, remove the listner for better JS memory management
        resolve(user) // return user. If the user is not logged in, this will be null.
      },
      reject
    )
  })
}
```

In `router.js`, for each route, use `meta` to define which routes needs authentication. Then, in the `router.beforeEach()` (i.e. router guard) use `getCurrentUser()` function.

Note: using `async` for router.beforeEach(). This ensures that route will be navigated only after the firebase auth is initialised.

```js
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from 'vue-router'
// Firebase
import { getCurrentUser } from "@/helper/firebase"


const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(),
  routes: [
    {
      path: "/",
      name: "WebsiteHome",
      meta: { title: "Jamku Portal", isAuth: false },
    },
    
    {
      path: "/admin",
      name: "Admin",
      meta: { title: "Admin", isAuth: true },
    },
    {
      path: "/pricing",
      name: "Pricing",
      meta: { title: "Jamku Portal Pricing", isAuth: false },      
    },
  ],
  }
});


router.beforeEach(async (to, from, next) => {

  // Add page title for browser
  document.title = to.meta.title || "Jamku Portal";

  // Initalize firebase if the route requires auth
  if (to.meta?.isAuth == true) {
    await getCurrentUser()
  }

  // Always call next() other wise Vue will never proceed further
  next();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Anyway, i saved it in cookie. when website loads, if cookie is exists i render navbar as if user logged in, and then double check after firebase listener returns

Comment: That didn't worked as well, now i don't display anything on navbar, until listener returns

Comment: What if user is in incognito mode, it is not a solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is caused because beforeEach is getting executed before firebase has fully finished initialization.

You can use onAuthStateChanged observer to make sure the vue app is initialized only after the firebase is fully initialized.

One way to fix it is to wrap the vue initialization code in main.js(new Vue( ... )) with onAuthStateChanged like this:

```
let app;

const auth = getAuth();
onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
  console.log("user", user);
  if (!app) {
    new Vue({
      router,
      vuetify: new Vuetify(options.Vuetify),
      render: (h) => h(App),
    }).$mount("#app");
  }
});
```

for version 7 firebase you can check this repo file
https://github.com/ErikCH/FirebaseTokenFrontend/blob/master/src/main.js