# Firebase.auth().currentUser turns to null every time the page restarts

Tags: firebase, vue.js, authentication, firebase-authentication

I am using firebase authentication with vue application
Every time I restart the page after I log in a user currentUser turns to null

```
  firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(this.email, this.password)
    .then(() => this.$router.push({name: 'Home'}))
    .catch(err => this.feedback = err.message)
```

and in vue router

```
 router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  if (to.matched.some(record => record.meta.requiresAuth)) {
    let user = firebase.auth().currentUser
    if (!user) {
      next({name: 'Login'})
    } else next()
  } else next()
})
```

I want the user to sign in once not every time the page restarts

Comment: Have answered here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/75572988/4050261

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is caused because `beforeEach` is getting executed before firebase has fully finished initialization.

You can use `onAuthStateChanged` observer to make sure the vue app is initialized only after the firebase is fully initialized.

One way to fix it is to wrap the vue initialization code in **main.js**(`new Vue( ... )`) with `onAuthStateChanged` like this:

```
let app;

...
firebase.initializeApp( ... );

firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(() => {
  if (!app) { // ignore reinitializing if already init (when signing out/login)
    new Vue( ... )
    ...
  }
})
```